# How can you convert numerical date to string date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert the following numerical date I'm getting after trimming ISO date in Javascript:

```
2022-03-04
```

To this:

```
April 3, 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const objDate = new Date("2022-03-04");
const monthFullName = objDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
const year = objDate.getFullYear();
const day = objDate.getDay()
const result = monthFullName + " " + day +", " + year;
// test
console.log(result);
```

You can play with it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/g6ucfbpa/15/